# Search Display Controller display additional tableView

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchbardisplaycontrol

Why another table view displayed after I inserted some word inside the search bar?

Before writing in search box

[image]

After writing in search box

[image]

Here is the code I am using:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", filteredFields[indexPath.row]];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", oriFields[indexPath.row]    ];
    }


    return cell;
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", searchText];
    filteredFields = (NSMutableArray *)[oriFields filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: nice shoots but where is the code???

Comment: its a default behaviour of the search display controller. if you dont want this then you should remove and add only search bar.

Comment: Code has been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A search display controller manages the display of a search bar, along with a table view that displays search results.

You initialize a search display controller with a search bar and a view controller responsible for managing the data to be searched. When the user starts a search, the search display controller superimposes the search interface over the original view controller’s view and shows the search results in its table view.

referenced by [apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: How do I disable the search display controller table view?

Comment: why you need to disable that

Comment: i think you want result in same tableview? @user3322987

Comment: ya, thats what I want.

Comment: Please help me on that. Should I just disable the Search Display TableView or I should hide the orignal tableView?

Comment: then you not go search display controller. add search bar control

Comment: because there are two control one is search bar and another search bar controller.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I should go for search bar only.

Comment: give a up vote you are eligible for that and get you too @user3322987

Answer (score 0):

you probably use a NSMutableArray as your data source... And you don't clean it when you type your search, so you have twice the values in it... Isn't it ?

Comment: I don't get you. By the way , I have updated the code, please help.